# How to find radius of circle when I have rect and center of rect?

Tags: android

I have draw circle on canvas with (somewhere in canvas, not in origin).

```
canvas.drawArc(mMenuRect, mStartAngle, 360, true, mRadialMenuPaint);
```

I need to split circle in eight parts/arcs. every arc is 45 degree and I need to draw line from center of circle to border of circle so the borders of every part is visible.
How to find radius of circle when I have rect and center of rect ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. This a basic math question. Go find your high school math book.

Comment: A rectangle is not a square so should the circle be the width of the shorter or longer side?

Comment: Radius is half the width or height of the rectangle.